# ComboBox not showing SelectedValue

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a problem with `ComboBox`. It doesn't show a value when I try to set it to show data from a database. The `ComboBox` has items from an array in app.xaml.

This is the code:

#### app.xaml

```
    <Application.Resources>
        <x:Array x:Key="Opcje_rodzaju" Type="local:ComboBoxItemString">
            <local:ComboBoxItemString ValueString = "N2"/>
            <local:ComboBoxItemString ValueString = "N3"/>
            <local:ComboBoxItemString ValueString = "O3"/>
            <local:ComboBoxItemString ValueString = "O4"/>
            <local:ComboBoxItemString ValueString = "M2"/>
            <local:ComboBoxItemString ValueString = "M3"/>
            <local:ComboBoxItemString ValueString = "INNE"/>
        </x:Array>
        <x:Array x:Key="Opcje_tacho" Type="local:ComboBoxItemString">
            <local:ComboBoxItemString ValueString = "Analogowy"/>
            <local:ComboBoxItemString ValueString = "Cyfrowy"/>
        </x:Array>
        <x:Array x:Key="Opcje_kontroli" Type="local:ComboBoxItemString">
            <local:ComboBoxItemString ValueString = "Sprawdzono"/>
            <local:ComboBoxItemString ValueString = "Nie sprawdzono"/>
            <local:ComboBoxItemString ValueString = "Stwierdzono nieprawidłowości"/>
        </x:Array>
    </Application.Resources>
```

#### window.xaml

```
    <ComboBox Height="29" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="343,154,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="116" ItemsSource="{StaticResource Opcje_rodzaju}" Name="combobox1"
                                  DisplayMemberPath ="ValueString" 
                                  SelectedValuePath="ValueString"                                      
                                  SelectedValue="{Binding Rodzaj_poj, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

#### window.xaml.cs

```
    combobox1.SelectedValuePath = "ValueString";
    combobox1.DisplayMemberPath = "ValueString";
    combobox1.ItemsSource = "Opcje_rodzaju";
    combobox1.SelectedValue = k.Rodzaj_poj;
```

Comment: If you open the drop-down (that doesn't display a value), does the expected item appear to be selected in the drop-down list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your model is defined like this:

```
public class ComboBoxItemString
{
    public string ValueString { get; set; }
}
```

the property `Rodzaj_poj` which is bond to the `SelectedValue` of the `comboBox`, needs to be a `string` not a `ComboBoxItemString` object

```
 private string _rodzaj_poj;
    public string Rodzaj_poj
    {
        get
        {
            return _rodzaj_poj  ;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_rodzaj_poj   == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _rodzaj_poj   = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

finally you need to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface so that once the `Rodzaj_poj` is changed, the interface will be notified

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Rodzaj_poj = "N3";
    }

  //.. 
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

}
```

Comment: OK. I've done this earlier and works well in datagrid, but Rodzaj_poj is a datafield from database which I want to display in combobox. Any suggestions??

Comment: the value of that property (Rodzaj_poj ) is always within the combobox itemsource, that you've defined ?

Comment: yes, it's been written to database, then when i double click od datagrid row i get values and i want to show it to edit data. k is reference to data row

Comment: then i don't see where the problem is !!, when you get the value from the datagrid (or from the database) set the Rodzaj_poj property, Rodzaj_poj =vallueFromDataGrid !

Comment: it's a problem with combobox not Rodzaj_poj. Rodzaj_poj is a field in database and I want to display that field in combobox. I set combobox1.SelectedValue = k.Rodzaj_poj but it's not working.

Comment: well you are doing it wrong, first of all this (combobox1.ItemsSource = "Opcje_rodzaju";) has no sense, remove it. the Itemsource was already binded using the collection you defined in the static resource,
second,  depanding on how you retrieving the data from the database, the Rodzaj_poj needs to be mapped in your code behind that's why you need to define an exact same property in your code behind, once you get the value from the DB using (k.Rodzaj_poj ) affect the result to the locally defined Rodzaj_poj,
Third, if your problem is with retrieving from the DB, you should include that is ur Q

Comment: thanks for help. now it's working. i need to get new object of ComboBoxItemString class then put value from database and at last set selectedvalue in combobox. once again thanks for help

Comment: I've got another problem. I set combobox.selectedvalue but i have nothing in window. WHY???. I override NotifyPropertyChanged and nothing change. please help

Comment: In addition to setting the `SelectedValue` property, set the `Text` property as well.

Comment: There was a little mistake by my side. I just forgot set datacontext to this and now everything works great.